# Set data of a Multiple Select2 element through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, jquery-select2

I'm loading multiple values into a Select2 element through Javascript, ajax and jquery. While the data is loading properly and can be accessed once loaded, I'm unable to set stored data in the Select2 element.

Edit: I'm using Select2 v3.5.

My code:

HTML:

```
<input class="jsData" style="width: 100%"  id="select2Data"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(".jsData").select2({
                        ajax: {
                            minimumInputLength: 4,
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            url: '<%=Url.Action("GetData","Controller")%>',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: function (term) {
                                return {
                                    sSearchTerm: term
                                };
                            },
                            results: function (data) {
                                return {
                                    results: $.map(JSON.parse(data), function (item) {
                                        return {
                                            text: item.term,
                                            slug: item.slug,
                                            id: item.Id
                                        }
                                    })
                                };
                            }
                        },
                        multiple: true
                    });
```

So, this creates a Select2 element where I can traverse to and from a database and load data depending on what I've typed. I can also access the data (entered by the user) using the following line:

```
$('.jsData').select2('val')
```

The above line returns an array, which I can store in the database. My current objective is to set the stored data back into the Select2 element. Any help in this matter would be most welcome.

Update: A relevant link for what I want to accomplish:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic

I want the example of setting multiple elements in Select2. However, the difference would be in the fact that the example in the Select2 documentation brings data at the time of loading the page, while I will be making trips to fetch the data.

Comment: In the Select2 docs it look like the prop is `processResults` instead of `results` like you show in your sample code.

Comment: I'm using Select2 v3.5, where `results` are used. As far as I know, `processResults` is used in v4.0 and above.

Comment: I'm able to make it work using v3.5.4 and a different data source. Can you verify your data source is returning data?

Comment: The problem is with _setting_ the value of the Select2 element. I am able to make continuous ajax trips to the controller and retrieve data according to what the user is typing, that isn't a problem. However, I'm trying to _set_ the data in the Select2 element.

(contd.) Basically: If I've entered some data, I can access the array of the entered data, and store it in the database. My aim now is to bring the data from the database and load it back into the Select2 element, for future modification by the user.

Comment: the solution below is updated to show how to set the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Select2 v3.5.4 docs](http://select2.github.io/select2/) are a bit confusing around this. I think there's a typo in the docs that's misleading.

First, notice that when I retrieve the data from the remote source I'm returning it as an object in the format of `{id: ##, name: NAME}`.

The first step is to add the `initSelection` parameter and pass the function to retrieve the previously selected items.

The next step, where I believe there's a typo, is to define the `formatSelection` parameter (not the `formatResult` it states in the docs). This function defines how the previously selected result is displayed. In this case I'm merely showing the `name` property of the result.

The `formatResult` parameter defines how newly selected options are displayed. You'll notice `formatResult` and `formatSelection` are the same below. I could have reused a single function but felt this was better for demonstration.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function formatResult(data) {
    return data.name;
  };

  function formatSelection(data) {
    return data.name; 
  }

  $(".jsData").select2({
    ajax: {
      minimumInputLength: 4,
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      results: function(data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(user) {
            return {
              name: user.name,
              id: user.id
            };
          })
        };
      }
    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
      var id = $(element).val();
      if (id !== "") {
        $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id, {
          dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
          callback(data);
        });
      }
    },
    formatResult: formatResult,
    formatSelection: formatSelection,
    multiple: true
  });
});
```

Here's the full working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function formatResult(data) {
    return data.name;
  };
  
  function formatSelection(data) {
    return data.name; 
  }

  $(".jsData").select2({
    ajax: {
      minimumInputLength: 4,
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      results: function(data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(user) {
            return {
              name: user.name,
              id: user.id
            };
          })
        };
      }
    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
      var id = $(element).val();
      if (id !== "") {
        $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id, {
          dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
          callback(data);
        });
      }
    },
    formatResult: formatResult,
    formatSelection: formatSelection,
    multiple: true
  });
});
```

```css
.jsData {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input class="jsData" style="width: 100%"  id="select2Data" value="10"></input>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll test it out, but glancing through it I think the initSelection bit should do the trick.

Comment: **Update**

Turns out, the solution is actually simpler than I thought!

All I did was: Store the Value and the Text separately in the database, and assign them to the _**data**_ part of the Select2, rather than the **_val_**. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Nice. I guess this would work if the selected values and their associated data do not change.